# SELECT only rows with higher ID than the last one matching a certain criteria?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

Let's say I have a SQLite 3 database that looks something like this:

```
ID    COMMAND     MESSAGE
------------------------------------------
1     start       abc
2     foo         xyz
3     bar         123
4     start       Hello
5     xxx         World
6     yyy         !
```

I want to select only the rows after (and including) the last `start` command, i.e.

```
4     start       Hello
5     xxx         World
6     yyy         !
```

Is this possible to do with pure SQLite, or should I do this in the application code (which is PHP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `id` for the last start and then use that for filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id >= (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.command = 'start');
```

Answer (score 0):

Badcash:

I would suggest *exactly* what Gordon Linoff suggested.

A good way to do this would be by utilizing subqueries. Assuming that the structure of your database holds from the example you gave, and that the IDs are sequentially incrementing, you could find the ID of the last START command (using a subquery) and then use that subquery to filter in your main query. You might consider something like this:

```
SELECT
    myTable.ID
    myTable.COMMAND,
    myTable.MESSAGE

FROM
    myTable

WHERE
    myTable.ID >= ( SELECT MAX(myNewTable.ID) from myTable myNewTable WHERE myNewTable.COMMAND = 'start');
```